# Trying to use IF formula next to each other in a row, however in the next column the value is in the cell below where the ArrayFormula is entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently got an issue in Excel / Google Sheets, where I have ArrayFormulas in cells next to each other but when it gets the value, it is putting it into the cell below, screenshot attached:

Issue where value should be in the cell underneath `EEYE1-2` but instead it's in the cell underneath

[image]

Formula being used in the cell underneath EEYE1-1: `=IF(E11=O30:O36,N30:N36,"")`

Formula being used in cell underneath EEYE1-2: `=IF(F11=O30:O36,N30:N36,"")`

Does anyone know what is causing the issue / how to resolve?

Comment: use `FILTER()`: `=FILTER(N30:N36,E11=O30:O36)`

Comment: Thank you so much, that's working :)

Comment: Is there any way of getting it it instead of showing #N/A to show a blank cell instead if no data found?

Comment: in Excel: `=FILTER(N30:N36,E11=O30:O36),"")`

Comment: Hi, would that work as there's a missing '(' isn't there?

Comment: `=FILTER(N30:N36,E11=O30:O36,"")`

Comment: Hi,

I've now got two results showing underneath each other for the filter, is there any way of just getting the latest date to show from the arrays?

Comment: Use SORT() to sort it descending and in EXCEL you can use `@` to only return the first record. `=@SORT(FILTER(N30:N36,E11=O30:O36,""),1,-1)`

Comment: Thanks for that Scott, is there any way of carrying this formula over to Google Sheets also, as I've been asked to recreate my excel document on there also but wouldn't know how to get working.

Comment: Doesn't opening the same file in google sheet, then 'save as' will work?